# Swift: What does this error: 'private(set)' modifier cannot be applied to read-only properties mean?

Tags: swift, computed-properties

I am bit confused if we can create computed property which is read-only Somethig like:

```
extension ToMyClass {
    private(set) var isEmpty: Bool {
        return head == nil
    }
}
```

While trying to create I got following error:

```
 error: 'private(set)' modifier cannot be applied to read-only properties
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are trying to set a modfier for a computed property, which is always read-only

The code below was taken from: [The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html)

```
struct TrackedString {
    private(set) var numberOfEdits = 0
    var value: String = "" {
        didSet {
            numberOfEdits += 1
        }
    }
}
```

It should be a stored property

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really missed the point that **"computed property, which is always read-only"**

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error but for a totally different reason. My code was as such:

```
protocol Foo {
    var bar: String { get }
}
class Baz: Foo {
    private (set) let bar: String // Error
    
    init(bar: String) {
        self.bar = bar
    }
}
```

I just had to change:

```
private (set) let bar: String
```

to:

```
private (set) var bar: String
```

`let` makes properties immutable and that was causing issues.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say, you have a struct -

```
struct StudentData {
    let id: String
    private(set) var maxScore: Int 

    var scoreNotUptoMark: Bool {
        return maxScore < 60
    }
    
    init(id: String, score: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.maxScore = score
    }
    
    mutating func scoreUp(by score: Int) -> Int {
        self.maxScore = maxScore + score
        return maxScore
    }
}
```

If you add private(set) modifier to `id` or `scoreNotUptoMark` we will get an error stating -

```
private(set)' modifier cannot be applied to read-only properties
```

Have a look at the code, is there any way, one can set value to `id` after it is initialized. No, right?
A constant can only be initialized when it is declared with value or from the initializer of the struct or class, it belongs to. Hence it is a read-only properly.

Same goes for `scoreNotUptoMark`. Can you set any value to a computed properties? No, right?
So, by behavior, it is a read-only property