# private(set) with let properties - 'private(set)' modifier cannot be applied to read-only properties

Tags: ios, swift, var, access-modifiers, let

I'm already aware of how `private(set)` works. But the below code is give compile-time error,

```
class Person {
    private(set) let name: String //Error.
    private(set) let age: Int //Error.

    init(name: String, age: Int){
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

**Error:**

> 'private(set)' modifier cannot be applied to read-only properties

Since `name` and `age` are not read-only properties, it shouldn't give such an error.

If I use `let` instead of `var`, it is working fine. Just trying to know why?

Comment: `let` defines that the property can be initialized once and then never changed but `set` defines that the property can be changed any (multiple) times.

Comment: There is nothing like `set` on a `let`. `let` is only `get`. I hope you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`private(set) let` is a contradiction in terms. Any setter requires a `var`iable.

Please be aware that assigning a default value to a property is not **set**ting the property in terms of initialization. For this reason the `didSet` property observer is not called after assigning a default value to a property.

In Swift there is only **one** case to use `private(set)`: If the class contains code which modifies the variable

```
class Foo {
    let name : String
    private(set) var expiryDate : Date

    init(name: String, expiryDate: Date){
        self.name = name
        self.expiryDate = expiryDate
    }

    func extendExpiryDate(to newDate : Date) {
       expiryDate = newDate
    }
}
```

If the property is only initialized during `init` it's a constant – as correctly mentioned in the other answers – so declare it as `let` constant. Unlike other programming languages Swift provides explicit constants with the benefit of more security, less memory usage and better performance.

Comment: Apple could be better by also suggesting 'Change let to var?'

Answer (score 1):

Let are constants ... you cant change their value one you assign them. Thats why they are considered readOnly ... so error is valid ... either convert them to var if you want to set them after assign them any value or remove private(set) and make them just private

happy coding =)

Answer (score 0):

They are read-only, because you’ve declared them with `let`, not `var`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a private setter when it is a `let` constant.
Just initialize it in the constructor or on the same line as the declaration.

If you want to change it outside of the constructor, you need to make it a `var`

Answer (score 0):

From the [Swift.org](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html) under Getters and Setters

> You can give a setter a lower access level than its corresponding
>   getter, to restrict the read-write scope of that **variable, property,
>   or subscript**. You assign a lower access level by writing
>   fileprivate(set), private(set), or internal(set) before the **var or
>   subscript introducer**.

Related post: [Swift: What does this error: 'private(set)' modifier cannot be applied to read-only properties mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45660160/2299040)